# Transition on div:after not works in safari

Tags: html, css

Transition on div:after not works in safari
Following is the code for that:

**HTML:**

```css
.bbtn {
  width: 151px;
  height: 48px;
  background: #ef2e41;
  margin: auto;
  margin-top: 32px;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
  -ms-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
  transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
  position: relative;
  border: 2px solid #5f121a;
}
.bbtn input {
  font-size: 25px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  text-align: center;
  color: #fff;
  background: none;
  border: 0;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 6px 0;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 10;
}
.bbtn:hover {
  border: 2px solid #373737;
}
.bbtn::after,
.bbtn::before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.9s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: all 0.9s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: all 0.9s ease-in-out;
  -ms-transition: all 0.9s ease-in-out;
  transition: all 0.9s ease-in-out;
  width: 0%;
  height: 100%;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background: #202020;
}
.bbtn:hover::after {
  width: 100%;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.9s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: all 0.9s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: all 0.9s ease-in-out;
  -ms-transition: all 0.9s ease-in-out;
  transition: all 0.9s ease-in-out;
}
```

```html
<div class="bbtn">
  <input name="" type="submit" value="search">
</div>
```

Here you can find my [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sLfh5Lwu/).

Comment: please explain what exactly you are doing, probably with the help of an image, insert your html, format the code and reduce the css to the minimum it takes to reproduce the problem

Comment: my html is    <div class="bbtn"> <input name="" type="submit" value="search"></div>

Comment: here is the reduced css

Comment: .bbtn { width:151px; height:48px;  background:#ef2e41;margin:auto; margin-top:32px; -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;   position:relative; border:2px solid #5f121a; }
.bbtn input {  font-size:25px; text-transform:uppercase; text-align:center; color:#fff; background:none; border:0; width:100%; padding:6px 0; position:relative; z-index:10;}
.bbtn:hover {border:2px solid #373737;}

Comment: .bbtn::after, .bbtn::before {  content: "";    position: absolute;  -webkit-transition: all 0.9s ease-in-out;  width:0%; height:100%; top:0; left:0;background:#202020;}
.bbtn:hover::after { width:100%;-webkit-transition: all 0.9s ease-in-out; }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What is your safari version? It is only supported Safari 6.1 and above.

See : http://css-tricks.com/transitions-and-animations-on-css-generated-content/

Comment: i am checking safari in my windows 7, i have safari 5.1.7.

Comment: as you can see in the link, transition for `:before` and `:after` elements are not supported for that version.